# get values from contact form 7 wp plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using  [contact form 7 plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) in my blog.I am having donate option in the form with price option in radio button. user can select and submit.After submitting the form it should redirect to the paypal. with selected price .

i tried

> on_sent_ok: "location =
>   'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=xxxx@india.com&currency_code=USD&amount=100&return=http://http://cratecreative.com/norpac&item_name=contribution';"

in additional  option in form management. But here value of price is static . I need to change that value what user selects.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change the `on_sent_ok' to:

```
on_sent_ok: 'my_redirect();'
```

then create that `my_redirect()` function in the page that displays the form:

```
<script>
    function my_redirect() {
        var price = document.getElementById('PRICE_FIELD').value;
        var url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=xxxx@india.com&currency_code=USD&amount='+price+'&return=http://http://cratecreative.com/norpac&item_name=contribution';
        window.location = url;
    }
</script
```

and done!
Just make sure that you correct the email in that url and replace `PRICE_FIELD` with the actual id of the price field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where should i place the script in plugin or theme files.

Comment: Hi! May I ask where should I put the script tags?

Comment: Hi @bainternet! I tried this solution but couldn't get it to work. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712480/how-to-add-form-field-value-to-query-parameter-to-contact-form-7-on-sent-ok-redi I would love to see if you could help me troubleshoot it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This whole code goes in the additional settings box, changing the "xxxx@example.com" to your Paypal email and the `"amount=100"` to your own amount ex-`"amount=25"` or `"amount="50"`. Also be sure to change the "return" page to your own URL once they complete the payment:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=xxxx@example.com&currency_code=USD&amount=100&return=http://http://cratecreative.com/norpac&item_name=contribution';"
```